# How to integrate a web application

Tags: java, servlets, integration

I have been developed a web application using java servlet at server side and html ajax javascript at client side.

A web application is already running at production server and now i have to integrate the newly developed application.

should i just give the link on the homepage of existing application?

but the newly developed application has it's own `web.xml` and also the existing application must be having `web.xml` whether i am not sure how to procedd. please give me any idea to integrate

what should i do for the integration.

Comment: what integration you want? since from your post seems its an independent app.So you need to tell what exactly you mean by integration here

Comment: Can't you just deploy the two wars at two `context root`s and a link in both app's menu to jump to the other app. If they share single login, you may want to implement SSO for single validatation. Apart from that there is not much seem to integrate.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi yes, there are two independent web application but have to make one application without changing anything in existing application.

Comment: @Nishant yes this is what i wanted to do the same as you said. but the problem is sharing the login. newer application doesn't have loginkind of thing while existing one has and i wanted to use the login of existing application in newer application

Comment: @user1010399 there are two ways, (1) Keep login mechanism in app#1. Refactor the code in such a way that the newer app could validate/authorize/authenticate the user. If not logged in the newer app redirects the user to older app login page with a `return_url` back to newer app. (2) Refactor the code in both apps to use something like `JOSSO` or `CAS` that provide token based SSO.

Comment: @Nishant ohh great, you got my point. many thanks. in my case, I'd prefer to follow the `case 1` by aadding the authentication feature in newly App but how a `context_A` communicates with `context_B`. Any idea on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can get, you want to give a link in the home page of your existing web application in production pointing to your new web app which you developed.

Your new web app is independent application, with its own web.xml, you can deploy it by building a separate war file and deploy it to your server.

For changing the link in the home page of your existing web application, if it is a plain html page or if it is a JSP page, then change the link in home page and then you can do hot deployment. Simply deploy the war file again. your server will automatically replace the html and jsp pages.

Comment: thanks Rao. I agree with your first & second paragraph but how to use the existing authentication if the context are different. by giving the link it switches from one to other but will it work the authentication when switch from existing to newer by clicking on link??

Comment: this you can achieve using Single Sign on functionality which tomcat provides, you have not mentioned what container you are using, similar to tomcat all containers provide functionality for single sign on. In short using Single sign on, you can maintain session across multiple applications. If you are using tomcat, please check the documentation of tomcat for how to do single sign on http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html.

Comment: Thank Rao. yes i'm using `Apache Tomcat`.